# Maven doesn't deploy correct pom file

Tags: java, maven, deployment, metadata, pom.xml

I use mvn :

```
mvn deploy
```

It copy to repository war file and its metadata

```
myapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

The problem that pom.xml from build directory doesn't copied correct! In the end of file always missing few rows.
This problem happens only on Linux, on Windows all ok.
What I could check to narrow the origin of problem?
I have already checked for incorrect characters in pom.xml - but all seems correct.

Comment: You're not running out of disk space on the Linux box?

Comment: no, manually file copied without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea what you doing,but from that what I read, you have a problem with filtering/copy resources in Maven (if using).

If you give more information it will be good.

In a meantime, check [this](http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/careful-with-your-binary-resources/)

Hope, this helps.